# Java function field of wildcard generics (wildcard capture error?)

Tags: java, function, generics, wildcard

I'm trying to use a wildcard function as a field within a class. The idea is that I can hot swap the function from outside the class with a public helper function (e.g., in a test class). Here is the sketch of the field wildcard function:

```
class Foo {
  private Function<?, ?> bar;

  public <T, R> void setBar(Function<T, R> baz) {
    this.bar = baz;
  }

 // ...
}
```

The compiler does not complain about any of this code; however, if I were to try and utilize the field function `bar` within `Foo` I get errors of the sort `... capture#1 of ?` (a wildcard capture error). Here is an example of how I would use the field function `bar`:

```
class Foo {
  private Function<?, ?> bar;

  public <T, R> void setBar(Function<T, R> baz) {
    this.bar = baz;
  }
  
  public doSomeMethod() {
    // ...
    if (this.bar != null) {
      // OutputType is hardcoded, as in input's type.
      // When `setBar` is called, function type must be correct.
      OutputType baz = bar.apply(input);
    }
  }
}
```

The outside caller would then be something in line with

```
public static void main() {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  Function<InputType, OutputType> myFunc = x -> x.inputToOutput();
  foo.setBar(myFunc);
  foo.someCalculation();
}
```

---

How would I fix this wildcard capture error, or is there a way to salvage the general idea? The key is to be able to set the function outside of the class (such that it can be tuned in a test class).

Comment: Why are you not just declaring `Bar` as `Function<InputType,OutputType>`? Please use Java naming conventions, by the way.

Comment: By hot swap, I also mean it changes its input and output types. And sorry I started coding Java a month ago, what naming convention am I not adhering to?

If it's about using Foo/Bar/Baz, I can go into my exact situation, but this summarizes the core concept I'm lacking.

Comment: How can the types change? `someMethod()` needs it to return `OutputType`. It isn't clear from your example where `input` comes from. For naming conventions, see https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html

Comment: I think you should provide a compileable, runnable example which is closer to your actual needs.

Answer (score 1):

A `Function<?, ?>` is a function that has some unknown type as input parameter, and some other unknown type which it returns.

For the 'returns' thing, well, it's java, so at least it's `Object`. But for the input type thing you're just hosed, you **cannot call this function, period** - it might be a function that maps Strings to Integers, in which case you must pass a string. Or it is a function that maps Path objects to Strings, in which case you must pass a Path instance. The compiler won't let you take a try-and-pray approach on this: It won't let you write code that is nonsensical, and trying to call a function that turns Paths into Strings, by passing it a String - that is nonsensical.

The code you've pasted does not show how you can make this code sensical, mostly because it misses details.

For example, `Foo` probably needs the T and R type:

```java
class Foo<T, R> {
  private Function<T, R> bar;

  public void setBar(Function<T, R> baz) {
    this.bar = baz;
  }
  
  public R someMethod(T thingie) {
    return bar.apply(thingie);
  }
}
```

If you insist on storing that function in the field, you're pretty much forced into the above, there's no other way: You need to 'track' that the paramtype and returntype of the function matches when you actually go to use it, and there's no other way to do that.

You can also do it in one go, and pass the function as part of the method invoke:

```
public <T, R> R someMethod(Function<T, R> func, T in) {
  return func.apply(in);
}
```

Remember: Generics **LINK THINGS** - There is no point to them unless the typevar is used in at least 2 places. `class Foo<T, R>` declares them. So does `public <T, R> foo() {}`. The other places are 'usages', and you want at least 2. Generics are compiled-checked documentation, they do nothing at runtime.

Let's say you want to write a method, and you want to say that the return type of it, is the same as its first parameter type, but it can be whatever the user wants. Let's say a no-op operation that just prints the param and then returns it. Without generics, you **cannot do it**:

```
public Object printMe(Object in) {
  System.out.println(in);
  return in;
}
```

Because this method 'undoes' the typing. You can't write `printMe("hello").toLowerCase()`. The spec of this method does not promise that it returns the parameter - it merely promises that it returns some Object.

With generics you can do it, because they link things:

```
<T> T printMe(T in) {
  System.out.println(in);
  return in;
}
```

Now you can write `printMe("hello").toLowerCase()` just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the crash course and detailed explanation. Sorry for misleading about the `someMethod` return type. I found that using `Object` and a helper function could help me get around the input type issue (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rzwitserloot for his explanation, and apologies for misleading that `someMethod` needed to have the same return type as the function (although irrelevant).
I have no such requirement, and the solution was to simply make a helper function, with an `Object` input to wrap the `apply` call.

```java
private Function<?, ?> bar;

public <T, R> setBar(Function<T, R> baz){
  this.bar = baz;
}

private <T> T executeBar(Object input){
  return ((Function) this.bar).apply(input);
}
```

Now `someMethod` "works" as desired

```java
public void doSomeMethod(){
  // ...
  ​if (this.bar != null) {
    OutputType y = executeBar(input);
  }
  // ...
}
```

This has unchecked warnings, but those can be suppressed (I'm a C programmer by tenure, so I prefer the compiler let me do stupid things anyways).

---

These function calls are really just for testing cases, and are only meant to signal extra test, or throw errors. Therefore the return type has zero effect on the method and in reality are consumed by something entirely different than the method indicated. I again apologize if the abstraction distracted from my core question about `Function<?, ?>`.