# How can generics in functions be used to avoid duplicate code?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a specific question about the usage of generics in Kotlin.

I want to create a function which takes a generic `T` as an argument.
It uses that to assign `name` from one of the classes: `Class1` or `Class2` to the local variable `testString`.

Unfortunately this is only possible when I check the type of the argument with the if conditions.

This leads to duplicate code. If I try to avoid that and use Line 12 I get this error during compile time: `Unresolved reference: name`

Is it possible in Kotlin to avoid the if conditions and use the testString assignment only once when the classes you are going to use have the same property with the same name?

Code:

```
fun main() {
    val class1 = Class1("Foo1")
    val class2 = Class2("Foo2")
}

class Class1(val name: String)
class Class2(val name: String)

fun <T> doStuff(classOneOrTwo: T) {
    var testString: String

    testString = classOneOrTwo.name //not working: Unresolved reference: name

    if (classOneOrTwo is Class1) {
        testString = classOneOrTwo.name
    }
    if (classOneOrTwo is Class2) {
        testString = classOneOrTwo.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need generics here.

You can just write an interface that requires its implementers to have a `name` property.

```
interface HasName {
    val name: String
}
```

`Class1` and `Class2` should implement the interface:

```
class Class1(override val name: String): HasName
class Class2(override val name: String): HasName
```

Then `doStuff` can be written as:

```
fun doStuff(classOneOrTwo: HasName) {
    var testString = classOneOrTwo.name
    // ...
}
```

You *can* make `doStuff` generic:

```
fun <T: HasName> doStuff(classOneOrTwo: T) {
    var testString = classOneOrTwo.name
    // ...
}
```

But you don't gain anything in particular by doing so.

Non-reified* generics are the most helpful when you want to establish some kind of "link", whether it be between parameters, or between parameters and the return type. For example, if your method is supposed to return the same type of thing as it takes:

```
fun <T> doStuff(foo: T): T { ... }
```

Or your method takes two parameters, and the second parameter must be the element type of the first parameter, which is a mutable list:

```
fun <T> doStuff(list: MutableList<T>, t: T) { ... }
```

---

<sup>*</sup> This paragraph doesn't quite apply to [reified generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), which could be useful on their own.

Comment: The idea that generics create "links" is something I got from [this rzwitserloot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71367505/5133585). Credits where credits are due!

Answer (score 1):

`Class1` and `Class2` have nothing in common for the doStuff function to resolve the property `name` even though they were written exactly the same way, if you expect that just because you have a generic parameter `T` everything will be automatically be resolved, unfortunately the compiler doesn't know what `T` is here, aside from it being implcitly `Any?` type, (i.e `<T: Any?>`).

You're having a compile error here becase `name` is not a property of `Any?`

```
 classOneOrTwo.name //not working: Unresolved reference: name
```

However, calling the doStuff function compiles fine because everything in Kotlin is a direct or indirect child of  `Any?`

```
fun main() {
    val class1 = Class1("Foo1")
    val class2 = Class2("Foo2")
    
    doStuff(class1)
    doStuff(class2)
}
```

and if you try to invoke some function using `classOneOrTwo` param and pressed `cltr+click` on it, youll see its a function of the type `Any?`

```
fun <T> doStuff(classOneOrTwo: T) {
    ...
    ...
    classOneOrTwo.toString() // <-- ctrl + click this you'll see its a function of Any?,
```

You should create a hierarchy (`Inheritance`) where `Class1` and `Class2` can inherit something from, in  your case `name`

```
open class ParentClass(open val name: String)

class Class1(override val name: String) : ParentClass(name)
class Class2(override val name: String) : ParentClass(name)

fun <T: ParentClass> doStuff(classOneOrTwo: T) {
    Log.e("DoStuff", classOneOrTwo.name) // now this works find because
}
```

Now it works because you explicitly tell the compiler that `T` is a type of `ParentClass` where the `name` property exists, and is inherited by your `Class1` and `Class2`.

Back to your main function

```
doStuff(class1)
doStuff(class2)
```

prints,

```
 Foo1
 Foo2
```